# Get drop down menu value on Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Got a simple question. I would like to get a drop down menu value when a use clicks it. I tried to write the code on my own, but couldn't do it. Any helps would be appreciated.

My Jquery

```
 $("#week").change(function(){

     var input=$("week: select").val();

     alert(input);  //display undefiend
```

My Html

```
   <form id="week">
   <select>
    <option>Week 1</option>
    <option>Week 2</option>
    <option>Week 3</option>
    <option>Week 4</option>
    <option>Week 5</option>

   </select> 
  </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
$("#week select").change(function(){    
     var input = $(this).val();    
     alert(input);
});
```

Comment: @Kobi - The select is a *child* of `#week`, his code is correct.